# Protractor: Open new tab or new window(Chrome) in already opened window to test url which is in text format

Tags: javascript, protractor

what i am trying to do:

1. Open New Chrome browser
2. Invoke URL
3. Enter Credentials
4. Click Login button
5. Go to admin view
6. Copy url from app
7. open new tab (tab2)and paste it
8. Verify page and Close 2nd tab
9. Now do actions in first tab

when running the following script

```
    this.openNewWindow = function () {
      browser.driver.executeScript("$(window.open('https://url.com'))");
    }
```

i am getting below error message.
`window is not defined`.